# Windows service is stopped immediately after statring

Tags: c#, windows-services

I Wrote a windows service, you can find code below

```
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new AutoUpgradeServiceDemo()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

    }

//Service class
    public AutoUpgradeServiceDemo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Service Has been Started");
        //My logic goes here
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        //My logic goes here
        MessageBox.Show("Service Has been Stopped");
    }
```

after installing, i started it by manually. It is immediately closing showing following error.

[image]

Could anyone help me...

Comment: Is it throwing an exception?  You should put some exception handling in place.  Also, check the windows event log; there may be some useful information there.

Comment: Yes roryap i implemented Exception handling and all the code is exception free..currently i'm working on windows server 2008 r2...how to check event registry..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows services have no user interface. So you cannot show a message box from a service. If you want to report errors, the standard way is using event log.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    base.OnStart(args);
    //my stuff
    this.WriteEventLogEntry("My service started successfully", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows service must execute `OnStart()` in limited time, or is killed.
How many seconds? I don't remember, look in MSDN.
When service is killed in this scenario, not too much info is reported, maybe Your is killed by watchdog too?

If longer start-up is required I usually start new thread

```
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            MyXxxxxStarter.LogInfo("Try to start thread");

            worker = new Thread(WorkerThread);
            worker.Start();

            MyXxxxxStarter.LogInfo("Thread started ");

        }
```

I agree with TSungur, logging only by event log (in my code implemented in one place)